# No SMBIOS table found while emulating with QEMU?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, x86-64, osdev

I'm developing a minimal x86-64 OS from scratch and I am attempting to detect memory to be able to map the higher half of the virtual address space to all physical memory available.

From this link: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/mm.html, I think this is what the Linux kernel does also. Probably to be able to reach all physical addresses if the need arises at some point.

```
ffff888000000000 | -119.5  TB | ffffc87fffffffff |   64 TB | direct mapping of all physical memory (page_offset_base)
```

I want to do the same in my kernel but I need to detect the amount of physical memory installed currently on my system. I can always use the Memory Map returned by UEFI but this doesn't necessarily tell me how much memory is actually installed.

I'm emulating on QEMU and I thought of locating the SMBIOS table to do that. If I print memory from 0xf0000 to 0xfffff, I don't find the signature of the SMBIOS table:

```
(gdb) dump memory result.bin 0xf0000 0xfffff

user@user-System-Product-Name:~$ hexdump -C result.bin
00000000  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
0000fd00  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  2e 06 a0 1b 79 c7 82 45  |............y..E|
0000fd10  85 66 33 6a e8 f7 8f 09  08 aa 01 08 f8 02 00 f8  |.f3j............|
0000fd20  0c 00 00 19 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 d4 02 00 19  |................|
0000fd30  31 c0 2d 00 10 00 00 3d  00 00 00 ff 72 33 81 78  |1.-....=....r3.x|
0000fd40  10 78 e5 8c 8c 75 eb 81  78 14 3d 8a 1c 4f 75 e2  |.x...u..x.=..Ou.|
0000fd50  81 78 18 99 35 89 61 75  d9 81 78 1c 85 c3 2d d3  |.x..5.au..x...-.|
0000fd60  75 d0 83 78 24 00 75 ca  89 c3 03 58 20 75 c3 eb  |u..x$.u....X u..|
0000fd70  09 b8 bf bf bf bf 89 c5  eb fe 89 c5 e9 37 02 00  |.............7..|
0000fd80  00 31 db 89 de 89 e8 66  8b 5d 30 01 d8 72 3b eb  |.1.....f.]0..r;.|
0000fd90  03 40 72 36 85 c0 74 32  83 c0 07 72 2d 24 f8 8a  |.@r6..t2...r-$..|
0000fda0  58 17 f6 c3 20 74 ea 8b  48 14 81 e1 ff ff ff 00  |X... t..H.......|
0000fdb0  09 c9 74 dd 01 c1 74 02  72 d7 80 78 12 03 75 06  |..t...t.r..x..u.|
0000fdc0  eb 17 85 c0 75 06 89 c8  eb ca 31 c0 89 c6 85 f6  |....u.....1.....|
0000fdd0  75 02 74 fe e9 e4 01 00  00 85 c0 74 5f 83 c0 18  |u.t........t_...|
0000fde0  39 c8 73 58 80 78 03 10  74 1b 80 78 03 12 74 32  |9.sX.x..t..x..t2|
0000fdf0  8b 18 81 e3 ff ff ff 00  01 d8 72 40 83 c0 03 72  |..........r@...r|
0000fe00  3b 24 fc eb db 83 c0 04  66 81 38 4d 5a 75 2d 0f  |;$......f.8MZu-.|
0000fe10  b7 58 3c 01 c3 81 3b 50  45 00 00 75 1f 03 43 28  |.X<...;PE..u..C(|
0000fe20  eb 1f 83 c0 04 89 c3 66  81 3b 56 5a 75 0e 03 43  |.......f.;VZu..C|
0000fe30  08 83 c0 28 0f b7 5b 06  29 d8 eb 05 b8 00 00 00  |...(..[.).......|
0000fe40  00 e9 7c ff ff ff eb 60  0f 20 e0 0f ba e8 05 0f  |..|....`. ......|
0000fe50  22 e0 b9 80 00 00 c0 0f  32 0f ba e8 08 0f 30 0f  |".......2.....0.|
0000fe60  20 c0 0f ba e8 1f 0f 22  c0 ea 70 fe ff ff 18 00  | ......"..p.....|
0000fe70  e9 4d 01 00 00 b8 00 00  00 80 0f a2 3d 1f 00 00  |.M..........=...|
0000fe80  80 7c 21 b8 1f 00 00 80  0f a2 0f ba e0 01 73 14  |.|!...........s.|
0000fe90  b9 31 01 01 c0 0f 32 0f  ba e0 00 73 07 89 d8 83  |.1....2....s....|
0000fea0  e0 3f eb 02 31 c0 eb 02  eb cb 31 d2 85 c0 74 06  |.?..1.....1...t.|
0000feb0  83 e8 20 0f ab c2 b9 00  18 00 00 31 c0 89 04 8d  |.. ........1....|
0000fec0  fc ff 7f 00 e2 f7 c7 05  00 00 80 00 23 10 80 00  |............#...|
0000fed0  89 15 04 00 80 00 c7 05  00 10 80 00 23 20 80 00  |............# ..|
0000fee0  89 15 04 10 80 00 c7 05  08 10 80 00 23 30 80 00  |............#0..|
0000fef0  89 15 0c 10 80 00 c7 05  10 10 80 00 23 40 80 00  |............#@..|
0000ff00  89 15 14 10 80 00 c7 05  18 10 80 00 23 50 80 00  |............#P..|
0000ff10  89 15 1c 10 80 00 b9 00  08 00 00 89 c8 48 c1 e0  |.............H..|
0000ff20  15 05 e3 00 00 00 89 04  cd f8 1f 80 00 89 14 cd  |................|
0000ff30  fc 1f 80 00 e2 e5 b8 00  00 80 00 0f 22 d8 e9 05  |............"...|
0000ff40  ff ff ff fa bb 00 f0 8e  db bb 7a ff 2e 66 0f 01  |..........z..f..|
0000ff50  17 66 b8 23 00 00 40 0f  22 c0 66 ea 62 ff ff ff  |.f.#..@.".f.b...|
0000ff60  10 00 b8 40 06 00 00 0f  22 e0 66 b8 08 00 8e d8  |...@....".f.....|
0000ff70  8e c0 8e e0 8e e8 8e d0  eb 39 1f 00 80 ff ff ff  |.........9......|
0000ff80  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 00 00 00 93 cf 00  |................|
0000ff90  ff ff 00 00 00 9b cf 00  ff ff 00 00 00 9b af 00  |................|
0000ffa0  bf 42 50 eb 0a bf 41 50  eb 05 66 89 c4 eb 02 eb  |.BP...AP..f.....|
0000ffb0  f9 eb 90 e9 78 fd ff ff  e9 c4 fd ff ff e9 84 fe  |....x...........|
0000ffc0  ff ff b8 ff ff ff ff 48  21 c6 48 21 c5 48 21 c4  |.......H!.H!.H!.|
0000ffd0  48 89 e0 ff e6 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  |H...............|
0000ffe0  eb c3 90 90 90 90 90 90  00 00 00 00 56 54 46 00  |............VTF.|
0000fff0  90 90 eb ac 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90     |...............|
0000ffff
```

I did try to add the -smbios type=0 flag when I launch QEMU from the command line.

I was wondering how the Linux kernel, when it runs within QEMU, does to detect memory and hardware. Does it use ACPI tables instead? I think SMBIOS is much more easy to use.

Is SMBIOS reliable enough so that operating-systems that run on newer hardware can assume its presence?